# What's the difference between `{}` and `()` in these code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, expression, statements, destructuring

[Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

it says:

> the {a, b} on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.

```
var a, b;
{a, b} = {a:1, b:2};//Syntax Error!
({a, b} = {a:1, b:2}); // it works
```

what the '()' do in the second sentence?

why the  '{}' in it is considered an object literal?

Comment: Parentheses can only contain expressions: blocks are *statements*, but object literals or variable assignments are *expressions*.

Answer (score 2):

Statements must not start with braces in Javascript:
[Pitfalls of destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#_pitfalls-of-destructuring)

Alternatively, the following expression is possible:

```
"",{a, b} = {a:1, b:2};
```

It is only important that a statement does not begin with a brace, because code blocks start with one.

Comment: **Statements must not start with braces** - this is not right. you can execute, for example {}(a = 'test') and it works perfectly.

Comment: Andrii's comment is wrong. `{}({a, b} = {a:1, b:2});` is either interpreted as an empty object literal or as an empty block (each followed by a destructuring assignment expression). Due to ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) this line is converted to: `{}; ({a, b} = {a:1, b:2});`. That's it. Since neither an object literal nor an empty block itself is a statement, the code is valid.

Answer (score 2):

The first tries to assign a value to a block, which is not right.
The second is an equivalent to

```
{}({a, b} = {a:1, b:2});
```

So here you are calling a constructor, supplying the block of properties and assigning them values.

Answer (score 1):

may I simply cite the hilighted explanation right next to the sample you've linked:

I think it's pretty clear

> The ( .. ) around the assignment statement is required syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a:1, b:2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a:1, b:2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a:1, b:2}`

Answer (score 0):

We can't assign any values to any literals like array,object,string.

ex:
[a] = [1];

{a} = {1};

"a" = "b";

But we can assign value using comma separator

[a],{a} = {a:1};

**Output:**

[a]  -- [1]

{a}  -- {a:1}

**Note:**

1.Object literal should not be first in the initialization.

2.In string literal never store any value.

**()** - is qualto **return** statement

Whatever you given in **{}**, it will automatically execute itself;

To check just place the code **{return;}** anywhere in the function it will return the function.

Just look into code snipped for understanding.

```js
var a =5;b=6;
console.log(JSON.stringify({a,b}));
//Output: {"a":5,"b":6}

[a,b],{a,b} = {"a":1, "b":2};
console.log(JSON.stringify([a,b]));
console.log(JSON.stringify({a,b}));
//Output: 
//[1,2]
//{"a":1,"b":2}

var name = (function(){return "lotus"});
console.log(name);
//Output: function(){return "lotus"}

name = (function(){return "lotus"})();
console.log(name);
//Output: lotus

name = ({a, b} = {a:3, b:4});
console.log(JSON.stringify(name));
//Output: {"a":3,"b":4}
```